# Retorno de chave primária de um INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a `tabela_x`, onde o primeiro campo (`campo1`) é `primary key` e `autoincrement`.

Faço um simples `INSERT`:

```
$ins = " INSERT INTO tabela_x (`campo2`,`campo3`,`campo4`) VALUES ($c2, $c3, $c4) ";
$con -> query($ins)
```

Gostaria de obter o retorno desse insert, com o valor do `campo1`.

Sempre terei que fazer um `select` logo após o `insert` só para pegar esse valor ou tem alguma forma que eu executo a `query` do insert, tendo como retorno o valor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função `mysql_insert_id()`. Veja esse exemplo:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Isso mesmo professor ! No meu caso é `$con -> insert_id` (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php). ;]